# ASM to search for a String in .class file

Tags: java, parsing, search, bytecode

Hi I want to search for a particular string in  /java/lang/String.class file using ASM. I got to know that the following method does that

```
         @Override 
      public String readUTF8(int index, char[] buf) {
String value = super.readUTF8(index, buf);
constantPoolStrings.add(value);
return value;
      }
```

But not sure how to use it .I am posting my code, can you please tell me how it can be achived in this.

```
public class DemoClassReader {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
ClassVisitor v= new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM4) {
            @Override

public void visit(int version, int access, String name,
                              String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {

System.out.println(" class: "+name);
super.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
            }
                    } ;

InputStream in=String.class.getResourceAsStream("/java/lang/String.class");
ClassReader classReader=new ClassReader(in);
classReader.accept(v, 0);
    }
```

Comment: There are many different kinds of strings stored in the class file. What exactly you want to search? Eg, method name, type name, signatures, string literals?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. It can be any String like variable defined; String name="john myler" and I want to seach for john. how this can be achived??

Comment: Just look for all String entries in the constant pool. Looking at utf8 is going to get you all the strings which aren't used for constants too.

Answer (score 2):

For capturing string literals you can implement the following MethodVisitor:

```
ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(in);
classReader.accept(new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.V1_7) {
  public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, 
       String signature, String[] exceptions) {
    return new MethodVisitor(Opcodes.V1_7) {
      public void visitLdcInsn(Object cst) {
        if(cst instanceof String) {
           // capture your string
        }
      }
    };
  }
}, 0);
```

See [visitLdcInsn(..)](http://asm.ow2.org/asm40/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitLdcInsn%28java.lang.Object%29) in the JavaDoc.